# MULTICOMP MCAK304NBWB KEYPAD: What are the pins 8 and 9 connected to?

Tags: microcontroller, interface, keypad

According to the datasheet, the 7 pins are from the 4 rows and 3 columns. What are the other 2 pins connected to ? The image shows 9 pin outs.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are unconnected. Possibly for use on a different model with more features (more keys, background illumination or similar) which shares components with this one.

Comment: So there is no Vcc and GND here, right?

Comment: @BhavanaBRao Correct.

Comment: The data sheet says- Contact rating : 20mA, 24V dc. What does that mean?

Comment: That the keys (contacts) are not rated for any more than 24 V and 20 mA. This sets the limit for your pull-up voltage and current. Most implementations would be some kind of 3.3 or 5 volt matrix with perhaps 1 mA.